# uWSGI with Cherokee: first steps

Tags: python, wsgi, cherokee, uwsgi

Has anyone tried using uWSGI with Cherokee? Can you share your experiences and what documents you relied upon the most? I am trying to get started from the documentation on both (uWSGI and Cherokee) websites. Nothing works yet. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

---

Edit: To clarify, Cherokee has been working fine. I am getting the error message:

> uWSGI Error, wsgi application not found

So something must be wrong with my configurations. Or maybe my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, I just recently set this up in Ubuntu Lucid for a Pylons app.

First, I grabbed the latest cherokee from the team PPA.
https://launchpad.net/~cherokee-webserver/+archive/ppa

Next I installed the uwsgi latest into my virtualenv my app lives in via Pip which the uwsgi docs walk you through. 
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Install

My app was already deployed via mod_wsgi so I was looking to reuse my .wsgi file. I ran into an issue getting the syntax for the uwsgi call right so I got some great help on their mailing list:
http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2010-June/000347.html

So I went through the docs in the cherokee cookbook and replaced the uwsgi line with a tweaked version of what was replied in my mailing list question.

It works pretty sweet and almost outperformed mod_wsgi 2x in testing hits to a simple pylons app served page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I got the same error message: `wsgi application not found`. But that list question was useful. Glad to hear that uwsgi is performing well for you.

Answer (score 2):

I got cherokee + uwsgi + django running on lucid. It was a little tricky getting going (figuring out how to point uwsgi to the wsgi file was the hardest part for me, too), but I'm quite happy with the results. I documented the steps I took at http://blog.swwomm.com/2010/06/cherokee-django.html.

Comment: Good post! What are the benefits of using the uWSGI model rather than the flup/SCGI that Cherokee uses are part of the Django wizard?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the 'make' method of installation on the uwsgi docs.  Use 'python uwsgiconfig.py --build' instead.  That worked for me.  Cherokee, Django running on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Do you know what problem is caused by the `make` method?